# Skip over remaining errors in current file to next error in next file

Tags: spacemacs, evil, flycheck, compilation-mode, lsp-mode

## tl;dr

I am using `:cn` in Evil's Ex command line and would like to use `:cnf` as well, but it is not there, and I don't know what function to bind it to.

## Details

As a former Vim user who is slowly coming to see the light, I am using `:cnext` in Evil's Ex command line in Spacemacs to navigate errors from the Scala compiler/[SBT](https://www.scala-sbt.org/). I am currently fixing errors caused by missing `import`s: thus, I can add one line at the top of the file and fix numerous errors. As such, I would like to skip straight to the next file with problems, i.e. Vim's [`:cnfile`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html). `:cnf` is not bound, and I cannot find something appropriate to bind it to.

I did find that `:cn` is bound to `next-error`, which seems to be associated with [Compilation Mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Compilation-Mode.html). However that seems to be misdirection as `compilation-next-file` gives "Not in a compilation buffer".

## Even more Details

My setup includes the following, and I'm not entirely clear how much of this is relevant, so I'll list it all:

- [Spacemacs](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs)
- [Evil mode](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil)
- [Flycheck](https://www.flycheck.org/en/latest/)
- [LSP Mode](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode)
- [Metals](https://scalameta.org/metals/blog/2020/05/04/lithium.html)

Answer (score 2):

It's a minor glitch/bug in the Emacs error interface, `compilation-next-file` only works (at least as of Emacs 25) if you are in the buffer showing the error messages, not in the source file with the error.  Do something like `other-window` to get your cursor into error message buffer and `compilation-next-file` will work (and then you probably need to hit something like enter to take you back to the relevant source file.